# Basic PowerShell function not working

Tags: powershell

I have written this basic Powershell function that returns current UTC date and time:

```
Function UtcFileDate() {
    [System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ss")
}
```

But when I run it the interpreter says:

> The term is not recognized as the name of the cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

What am I missing here? What I do - put this function to a separate `helpers.ps1` file, open PowerShell console, import the file via `.\helpers.ps1`, then call it like `$x = UtcFileDate`. Same thing on both Windows 7 and Win Server 2008.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run `.\helpers.ps1` you are executing the script but your function will not be accessible from your session, hence the error.  You need to dot source the script (see the section `SCRIPT SCOPE AND DOT SOURCING` of [about_Scripts](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/Hh847841.aspx) ) to make its functions, variables, etc. available to your running session:

```
. .\helpers.ps1
$x = UtcFileDate
```